# Keep list fragment selected item position on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list fragment on the left of another fragment and is essentially the standard click an item and update the right fragment pattern. When they click an item in the list fragment they are choosing the news article category and I need to keep whatever one is selected when they rotate the device. How do I do that? My current code doesn't work.

My code is as follows:

```
public class SideMenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    ArrayList<SideItem> sideItems;
    SideAdapter sideAdapter;
    public SideMenuFragment() {
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        sideItems = new ArrayList<SideItem>();
                ...add bunch of items
        sideAdapter = new SideAdapter(getActivity(), sideItems);
        getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        setListAdapter(sideAdapter);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            sideAdapter.setSelectedItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("sidePosition"));
            sideAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("sidePosition", sideAdapter.getSelectedItem());
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (sideAdapter.getSelectedItem() != position) {
            sideAdapter.setSelectedItem(position);
            sideAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        switch (position) {
                      ...switch the fragment depending on position.
                    }
    }

    // the meat of switching the above fragment
    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        if (getActivity() == null)
            return;
        if (getActivity() instanceof HomeActivity) {
            HomeActivity a = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
            a.switchContent(fragment, title);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add your Fragment in xml if the Activity layout.
In Activity onCreate

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtfragmentid).setRetainInstance(true)
```

This means that the fragment will not be recreated on activity recreate.

Don't change your ListView in onActivityCreated - because it will be rebuilt every time orientation changes. If you set a new adapter - the states of children will be reseted.

Add checking for null or a boolean flag that the view already was created.
Next time onActivityCreated gets called, your list adapter should not change

```
if (sideAdapter == null) {

    sideAdapter = new SideAdapter(getActivity(), sideItems);
        getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        setListAdapter(sideAdapter);

}
```

Also, don't create new view in onCreateView instead use previously created one.

```
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    } else {
        // detatch from container and return the same view
        ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Currently trying some of these changes, will report back shortly.

Comment: After adding setRetainInstnace(true) and adding the adapter null check, things are working great now. I didn't change the onCreateView either.

Comment: The oncreateview is an unrelated (yet recommended) optimization.

Comment: You *really*, *REALLY* want to avoid retaining fragments that have views. If your fragment instance holds on to *any* references to any of its views or other access to the `Context`, you're going to leak the whole `Context` which is awful. You can see how many contexts are in memory using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo`

Comment: @RomanNurik: If we do not hold onto "references to any of its views" past `onCreateView()` being called on the new instance, and so long as we do not hold onto `Context` ourselves any other way, retaining a fragment with `Views` should be safe (or else represents a bug in the framework). With `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` deprecated, allowing fragments to be retained is important, and attempts to force developers to use view-less fragments for that will likely fail. I'd recommend that Lint rules be added to help ensure developers use retained fragments safely instead.

Comment: @RomanNurik how do you keep selected item ina gridview or/and listview after rotatoin??

Comment: @CommonsWare: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is deprecated but there is  onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance which does the same.