# removeAllViews() error when retaining fragment instance

Tags: android

I am trying to retain my fragment instance on orientation change. I use the below code in my fragment.

```
private View fragmentLayoutView;
private ListView myListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setRetainInstance(true);
    ...
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    if(fragmentLayoutView == null){
        fragmentLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragmentLayout,container,false);
    }
    else{
        ((ViewGroup) myListView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    return fragmentLayoutView;
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    myCustomCursorAdaptor = new MyCustomCursorAdaptor(getActivity());
    myListView.setAdapter(myCustomCursorAdaptor);
    ...
    }
```

But i get an error after `onCreateView()` has returned. The `removeAllViews()` line seems to be creating the problem.

**Logcat :**

```
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.www/com.mypackage.myActionBarActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3895)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:168)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.mypackage.myActionBarActivity.onCreate(myActionBarActivity.java:20)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     ... 12 more
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3739)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3610)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3555)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3531)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:310)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-17 23:57:08.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     ... 25 more
```

There is no error, but the listView disappears from the layout if i try the below options :

- remove the if-else and simply inflate every time
- do a getParent on the fragment layout instead of on the listView - `((ViewGroup) fragmentLayoutView.getParent()).removeAllViews();`,

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't `myListView` never be instantiated with this current code?

Comment: `onActivityCreated()` works fine as long as i remove the if-else block in `onCreateView()` and simply inflate the fragment. Why do you think the ListView would never be instantiated?

Comment: I just re-read and didn't realize that you're checking to make sure it gets instantiated before referencing it.  Does the error only trigger when you change orientation?

Comment: Yes the error is only after an orientation change

Comment: why are u removing the view?

Comment: I just followed the suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14836040/2105986 to retain fragment instance. Not really sure Why i need to do it.

Comment: Probably just to reuse the layout on orientation change instead of creating it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove all the views of the fragment layout's parent :

```
((ViewGroup) fragmentLayoutView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
```

Then check if the adaptor is null before initializing the adaptor and listview :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(myCustomCursorAdaptor == null){
        myListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        myCustomCursorAdaptor = new MyCustomCursorAdaptor(getActivity());
        myListView.setAdapter(myCustomCursorAdaptor);
    }
    ...
}
```