# Android freezes on ViewGroup.removeAllViews() with MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've got a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` that I create dynamically, using

`mapView = new MapView(DataManager.getInstance().getContext());`

This mapView gets attached to a parent through `addView(mapView)`. Somewhere later in my program, I want to remove this mapView by calling `parent.removeAllViews();`, but there android just stalls. The app freezes completely, and I've got no idea why. What can I do to resolve this?

Edit:

I have done some more research using a `CustomMapView`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

/**
 * @author Daniël van den Berg
 * @date 9/30/2015.
 */
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {
    public CustomMapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRemoved(View child) {
        super.onViewRemoved(child);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }


    public void remove() {
        onPause();
        onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I call the remove method before trying to remove the view, and that's where it hangs. The breakpoint at onPause does get triggered, but the one at onDestroy doesn't. I call both `onCreate()` and `onResume()` when it gets created. Calling `onDestroy()` without calling `onPause()` does work, though then `removeView(child)` hangs again. So apparently onPause is hanging my app. Does anybody have any ideas on what I could do to figure out what the problem is?

Edit:
Yet another addition, this problem only seems to occur when the map is removed from `public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {`. In this function I call the method that removes the view through `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: Could this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271074/removeallviews-error-when-retaining-fragment-instance help you

Comment: @eugensunic Unfortunately not, I have updated my question with some new findings.

Comment: It seems that Google finally, after two and a half years, responded to the bug report. As I'm not working on this project any more, and am not interested in the maps api, I will not be "doing their bidding" by attempting to reproduce the issue in one of their example codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this one took me a while, but I have finally figured it out. It seems to be either a bug or something that isn't documented very well. But apparently calling `MapView.onPause()` from

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
```

does not work. This will hang the app. I solved this by doing the following:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    myMethods();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }, 1);
```

and now it works perfectly fine. I'll report this as a bug to Google (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8681).